# In-App Purchase items are empty

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a new project that developed 3 months ago. It has tested using TestFlight up to v1.0 build#11. Now, my customer requests adding IAP items in the app. I've setup all items on Store then tried to fetch all valid items (10 items), but the response.products always empty, all items are invalid.

I've tried both dev & ad_hoc provisioning. Remove then install app several times. But I've got no luck. Do I need generate new provisioning after adding API items and API feature?

Comment: Assuming that obviously you didn't changed the bundle ID, does your app supports In-app Purchases (Capabilities)?

Comment: Bundle Id does not change. I also enable IAP in capabilities in project target.

Comment: I've tried to submit binary to Apple reviewer, then reject it immediately. And it works.